# VIM error: WARNING: The file has been changed since reading it!!! How to view the changes VIM is complaining about?

Tags: buffers, edit

Is there a quick way to see the differences VIM is describing?

Comment: `:!view %` might do it, but is not a diff. I think we have a Q somewhere about getting the diff…

Comment: Might be an easier way but you can save a copy, e.g. `:w %.tmp` then diff with the original `:!diff % %.tmp`.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new window, read file from disk into it and show the differences. Kind of this

```
vnew +read\ # | windo diffthis
```

More complete version is discussed at `:h diff-original-file`. Also, a ton of variations in personal configs/gists/similar SO topics etc.